# Moving a class from one tag to another using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to create a function in Javascript which advances some shapes (coloured cells in a table) across the page each time a key is released. I'm a total novice, so for now, I'm just trying to figure out how to move the "active" class from one `<td>` tag to another upon the user keying up.

```html
<table class="racer_table">
      <tr id="player1">
        <td class="active"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="player2">
        <td class="active"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Add the class attribute to the new cell; remove it from the old - done in reaction to the appropriate key event.

Comment: Add Onkeyup change the in the function or in selection of tr add the event listener

Comment: @Vijay thanks, could you show me an example of selecting the tr?

Answer (score 2):

You have an interesting challenge. Based on the HTML, I assume you want a multiplayer game. I'll leave that part up to you. But here is how you could do it for a single player (then just keep track of who is active and you can adapt it to two players):

Use `document.onkeyup` which if a function is assigned to it, will be called every time a key goes "up" (as in, when I press the "k" key, it goes down and then up so listening for the up is a full keypress). When the function is called, it is passed an event. We know the standard says a property called `keyCode` will exist on the event which is a numeric value. We can use that to identify which key was pressed.

So say we have this HTML:

```
<table class="racer_table">
  <tr>
    <td class="active"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And we style it so we can see the td as squares of color:

```
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

td.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Then use this JavaScript:

```
var UP = 38;
var DOWN = 40;
var LEFT = 37;
var RIGHT = 39;

var racerTable = document.getElementsByClassName('racer_table')[0];

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case UP:
    case LEFT:
      var cells = racerTable.getElementsByTagName('td');
      for (var i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        if (cells[i].className.indexOf('active') !== -1) {
          if (i === 0) {
            // do nothing, all the way left
          } else {
            cells[i].className = '';
            cells[i-1].className = 'active';
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      break;

    case DOWN:
    case RIGHT:
      var cells = racerTable.getElementsByTagName('td');
      for (var i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        if (cells[i].className.indexOf('active') !== -1) {
          if (i === (cells.length - 1)) {
            // do nothing, all the way right
          } else {
            cells[i].className = '';
            cells[i+1].className = 'active';
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wuc0mre/ (note, click onto the lower right pane with the blue and red circles and then use the up/down or left/right keys to move the red square)

Comment: Thanks very much @Cymen . Some questions: 1. why do you make the argument of the function (e)? and 2. what does (cells[i].className.indexOf('active') !== -1) mean?

Comment: @MaxineEllah I use `e` due to convention -- it is clearer to use `event`. But I could have used `theEvent` or `keyPressEvent` or whatever I wanted as I'm just defining the first argument to the function will be assigned to whatever I name it there. But I would have to be sure that I was consistent with the name (so when I checked the `.keyCode`, I'd have to use `theEvent.keyCode` or whatever I named it). I'll reply about next part separately.

Comment: @MaxineEllah So a DOM node has a property called `className` which is a string. For this HTML `<a class="a b c">hi</a>` the `a.className` when accessing the it as a DOM node would be `"a b c"`. So what I'm doing is checking if `cells[i]` has the class `active` or not -- `indexOf` returns `-` if the argument is not present in the string. Modern browsers have a much nicer `classList` property but unfortunately not all browsers support it so you can use it if that doesn't matter to you (google "mdn classList").

Comment: Great. And lastly (I hope), 1. What is the purpose of the second nested if statement? and 2. What do you mean by 'all the way left/right'? @Cymen

Comment: @MaxineEllah The second nested if statement is to handle if you are pressing up or left but are already on the first node -- if so, we don't want to do anything. For the lower part, it's the same thing -- if you press down or right and are already on the right-most cell (it's active), then don't do anything.

Comment: @MaxineEllah Oh, and if this answer is good for you, you can click the checkmark next to the up/down vote arrows on the answer to accept it. Thanks for posting -- it was fun to do this :).

Comment: Hi @Cymen could you please explain a bit more the purpose of putting the inequality operator !== -1 at the end of the first if statement?

Comment: @MaxineEllah Sure, think of it this way: we are going to walk over the list of cells looking for the one that has the `active` class. Only when we find that cell will we go inside the `if` clause and do something. So we look for active, once we find it, we go inside and remove active and set the next left/right active (unless we are all the way to one side and still going off the side -- then we don't do anything -- we could make it so if you went off the left, the cell all the way to the right was active and vice versa).